# json parse to JavaScript array with turn.js

Tags: javascript, php, turnjs

I'm new here,  I got problem with my script when display page flip using turn.js.
My page is come from mysql database store it in json format then parse to array in JavaScript to view by turn.js

Here's my code :

```
<body>
<?php
$json_array = Array();

include("setdb.php");
$query="select * from catalogue_page where catalogue_id='5'";    
$result=mysql_query($query);
$totalrec=mysql_num_rows($result);


 while ($hasil=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $data=  "images/pages/small/".$hasil['img_file_small'];

 array_push($json_array, $data);  
 }


 $json_array2 = array();

 $query="select * from catalogue_page where catalogue_id='5'";    
 $result=mysql_query($query);

 while ($hasil=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $data="images/pages/large/".$hasil['img_file_large'];

    array_push($json_array2, $data);  
  }

?>

<div class="magazine-viewport">
<div class="container">
  <div class="magazine">
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var page_image = Array();
var page_image_large = new Array();

page_image = JSON.parse( '<?php echo json_encode($json_array)?>' );

page_image_large = JSON.parse( '<?php echojson_encode($json_array2)?>'   



 );

......
......
 next script from turn.js
</script>
```

That script showing page starting from 1 coloumn not starting from 0 column

**in browser turn.js starting show the page from images/pages/small/2_5.jpg not images/pages/small/1_5.jpg**

my json parse is

```
( '["images\/pages\/small\/1_5.jpg","images\/pages\/small\/2_5.jpg","images\/pages\/small\/3_5.jpg","images\/pages\/small\/4_5.jpg","images\/pages\/small\/5_5.jpg","images\/pages\/small\/6_5.jpg"]' );
```

0 coloumn is `images\/pages\/small\/1_5.jpg` 
1 coloumn is `images\/pages\/small\/2_5.jpg`
....
next coloumn

Comment: help with correctly this script if I'm wrong

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the script excerpt above. You should ask a specific question on a programming problem. “I want to use X with library Y” is not a problem description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i was correctly my script and turnjs show page with charm  here my correct script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var page_image = new Array();
var page_image_large = new Array();

var tampung1 = JSON.parse( '<?php echo json_encode($json_array)?>');
var tampung2 = JSON.parse( '<?php echo json_encode($json_array2)?>');
var j=1;

for(i=0;i<<?php echo $totalrec?>;i++)
{
page_image[j] = tampung1[i];
page_image_large[j] = tampung2[i];
j++
}

 .....
 next turnjs script
</script>
```

any way thanks for attention.